# How to perform a like query TypeORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

Hello guys I'm trying to find all the results that have a in them. I have tried a couple of ways but the problem is nothing works. It just returns an empty array

```js
var data = await getRepository(User)
  .createQueryBuilder("user")
  .where("user.firstName = %:name%", { name: firstName })
  .getMany();
```

and something like this

```js
var data = await getRepository(User)
  .createQueryBuilder("user")
  .where("user.firstName like %:name%", { name: firstName })
  .getMany();
```

but nothing is working. All of these are returning me a empty array. Can somebody help me out thanks

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Correct way is:

```
 var data = await getRepository(User)
                  .createQueryBuilder("user")
                  .where("user.firstName like :name", { name:`%${firstName}%` })
                  .getMany();
```

Comment: Will this properly escape `firstName`?

Comment: I tested it... I think it does parameterize it.

Comment: @user3413723 I just tested this. It does escape quotes and other characters, but it does not (and could not) escape "%" and "_" characters.

Comment: SQL injection!!!!

Comment: Is there official documentation for this ? I couldn't find

Answer (score 120):

TypeORM provides out of the box `Like` function. Example [from their docs:](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md#advanced-options)

```js
import {Like} from "typeorm";

const loadedPosts = await connection.getRepository(Post).find({
    title: Like("%out #%")
});
```

in your case:

```js
var data = await getRepository(User).find({
    name: Like(`%${firstName}%`)
});
```

Comment: If you're coming here looking for `ilike` like I was, it appears it's coming in an upcoming release: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/5828

Comment: If the `firstName` is not a safe value, your solution is not protected against SQL injection

Comment: @LucaRoverelli how do I make it safe from sql injection? is it possible using same syntax?

Comment: not working on mongodb

Comment: @LucaRoverelli i think solution is protected against sql injection because here we are not building raw query. value will be injected as parameterized in sql query. We can check underlying query by enabling logging option in datasource.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the database function for concatenation. In postgres for instance:

```
 var data = await getRepository(User)
              .createQueryBuilder("user")
              .where("user.firstName like '%' || :name || '%'", {name: firstName })
              .getMany();
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems that all of the answers as of writing including the accepted answer by [pleerock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925151/pleerock) are vulnerable to SQL injection unless the user input has been sanitized beforehand.

```
 var data = await getRepository(User)
              .createQueryBuilder("user")
              .where("user.firstName like :name", { name:`%${firstName}%`})
              .getMany();
```

The fact that the above code is valid in TypeORM makes it so that any query of this style is vulnerable to data exfiltration. Imagining the following similar query:

```
 const data = await getRepository(User)
          .createQueryBuilder("user")
          .where("user.firstName like :name", { name: firstName })
          .getOne();
```

Un-sanitized data coming in from the user containing `%` character being sent into `firstName` in the above query (e.g. `let firstName = '%John'`) would allow a user to exfiltrate potentially private data about other users.

Hence, where the use case allows one should **ensure** that any user input is sanitized and any special characters are removed.

Alternatively, in MySQL, where the use case demands that special characters are present in the text a full text search may be more appropriate. However, this is more expensive to maintain.

Create fulltext search on relevant column and perform query

```
    export class User {
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id: number;

        @Index({fulltext: true})
        @Column()
        name: string;
    }

    const data = await this.repository
         .createQueryBuilder()
         .select()
         .where('MATCH(name) AGAINST (:name IN BOOLEAN MODE)', {name: name})
         .getOne()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = await  getRepository(User)
                        .createQueryBuilder("user")
                        .where("user.firstName ILIKE %q", {q:`%${VALUE_HERE}%` })
                .getMany();
```

This is how I do it. Hope it helps

Comment: This is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @tannerburton why? doesn't TypeORM sanitize the parameter, even if surrounded by %?

Answer (score 1):

### "typeorm": "^0.3.5"

With TyeORM and Mysql works this

```
import {Like} from "typeorm";

const loadedPosts = await UserRepository.find({
    where: {
      name: Like("%Mar%")
    }
});
```

And you can use this:

```
import {Like} from "typeorm";

const filters={
  name: 'Ca',
  age: '3'
}

const columnFilters={}
for(const i in filters){
  columnFilters[i]= Like(`%${filters[i]}%`)
}

const loadedPosts = await UserRepository.find({
    where: columnFilters
});
```

Answer (score -2):

using repositories i put it in the **where** clause for exemple :

```
let res = await this.trackingRepository.findAndCount({
      where: [{ username : Like(`%${searchValue}%`) },
              { action : Like(`%${searchValue}%`) },
              { ip : Like(`%${searchValue}%`) }],
      order: {
        [sortField]: sortOrder === "descend" ? 'DESC' : 'ASC',
      },
      skip: (current - 1) * pageSize,
      take: pageSize,
    });
```

Comment: you shouldn't interpolate values manually. Your code is susceptible to SQL injection

Comment: What will be the best way to replace it ?

Comment: Use query parameters. I'll update your answer to use query parameters.