# LIKE query with wildcard in TypeORM QueryBuilder

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

In my NestJS project I have this TypeORM query:

```
const users = await this.usersRepository.find({
  skip,
  take,
  order: sortingObject,
  join: {
      alias: 'user',
      leftJoinAndSelect: {
          country: 'user.country_id',
      },
  },
});
```

Now I only want to return the users with `John` in there name. In SQL this would be a `LIKE` query `LIKE %John%`.

In https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md there is no information about wildcard `LIKE` queries.

[How to perform a like query Typeorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814537/how-to-perform-a-like-query-typeorm) gives as a solution:

`.where("user.firstName like :name", {name: '%' + firstName + '%' })`

But then I am unable to use `skip` and `take` which is available when using `where()` instead of `find()`.

Any thoughts on how I achieve this with the TypeORM QueryBuilder?

Answer (score 7):

There are pagination methods (`.skip(int)` and `.take(int)`) in QueryBuilder.

Try something like this.

```
const users = await this.usersRepository
    .createQueryBuilder("user")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("user.country_id", "country")
    .skip(5)
    .take(10)
    .where("user.firstName like :name", {name: '%' + firstName + '%' })
    .orderBy("user.id", "DESC")
    .getMany();
```

For the details, please refer to the document:
[Using Pagination in TypeORM QueryBuilder](http://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/using-pagination)

Comment: My question is not how to use the skip/take methods but how to use these in combination with a wildcard LIKE query

Comment: You just need to add the `.where("user.firstName like :name", {name: '%' + firstName + '%' })` from your question into the query builder chain @michael-lam has posted above ... anywhere between the `createQueryBuilder("user")` and `.getMany()` lines.

Comment: Thanks @Timshel for the supplement. Edited the answer

Comment: For easier readability added syntax sugar
 ```.where("user.firstName like :name", {name: `%${firstName}%` }```

Answer (score 0):

To search with `find()`.
You can use `ILike` from `'typeorm'` to search with LIKE `query`.

In your case:

```
const users = await this.usersRepository.find({
  skip,
  take,
  where: {
      name: ILike(`%${ firstName || ''}%`)
  },
  order: sortingObject,
  join: {
      alias: 'user',
      leftJoinAndSelect: {
          country: 'user.country_id',
      },
  },
});
```

Note that, `import { ILike } from 'typeorm';`

Answer (score 0):

To complement the above answer written by [Hungnn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76107113/22894334)

To search with `find()`.
You can use `ILike` from `'typeorm'` to search with LIKE `query`.

In your case:

```
  const users = await this.usersRepository.find({
  where: {
    id: criteria?.id,
    name: ILike(`%${criteria?.name || ''}%`),
  },
  relations: {
    country: true
  },
});
```

You also can use `@ManyToMany()` or `@ManyToOne()` with `@JoinTable({ name: 'task_category' })` in your Entity class to avoid:

```
join: {
  alias: 'user',
  leftJoinAndSelect: {
      country: 'user.country_id',
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB and `.find()` I use own function MLike - MongoDB-Like.
`TypeScript`

```js
const user = await this.usersRepository.find({
  where: MLike(`%${name}`),
});
```

Where function body is

```js
export function MLike(value: string): { $regex: string } {
    const like = value.replace(/%+/g, '.*');
    return {$regex: `^${like}$`};
}
// example of use, MLike(`%1234`); -> { '$regex': '^.*1234$' }
```